# C.Vim plugin, adding Automatic Header to *.h file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have just downloaded and installed the [C-Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213) plugin for C/C++ development in Vim.

When I create a new .c file, a header is automatically created from a template - I want the same thing to happen when I create a new .h file.

Instead, I get the following warning (when creating new .h file):

```
template does not exist
```

How can I modify the plugin settings so that new .h files also have a template generated for them?

Comment: What plugin did you download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
let g:C_SourceCodeExtensions  = 'h cc cp cxx cpp CPP c++ C i ii'
```

The important part here to notice is the `h` at the begining of the string. For more information on why this works see `:h csupport-comm-frame`.

**Note:** in order to see the help documentation, make sure to run `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` after installing the plugin. Otherwise the documentation that comes with the plugin will not be installed.

Comment: +1 for helping me fix this - adding the line to .vimrc solved it however, I would like to understand what I just did :). When I use the help command you gave, I get: E149: Sorry, no help for csupport-comm-frame. Was that a typo on your part?

Comment: No, I don't think there was a typo. Assuming you installed everything in the zip file that came with the plugin, you also need to run `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` to generate all of the help files that came with the plugin.